# Magento jQuery tabs per attribute in list.phmtl

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and have some simple products, with custom attributes, being displayed in a category product listing.

I am looking to split the product listing by the products' custom attribute so each attribute has a list of products within  tags so I can use jQuery tabs to split the categories up.

I see that default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml generates the list of products:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

How would I go about splitting the products into separate divs by attribute?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the logic goes for splitting these products up, you could take the loaded product collection, and in a foreach loop check the attributes of each product and assign them to appropriate, new arrays.

For example:

```
<?php

$_productSegments = array(
    'attribute1' => array(),
    'attribute2' => array(),
);

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
    if ($_product->hasAttribute1()) {
        $_productSegments['attribute1'][] = $_product;
    }
    if ($_product->hasAttribute2()) {
        $_productSegments['attribute1'][] = $_product;
    }
}
?>

<?php foreach ($_productSegments as $_productSegment): ?>
    <?php if (!empty($_productSegment)): ?>
        <div>
            <?php // Whatever product info you want here. Use jQuery logic to make it into tabs ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productSegment as $_product): ?>
                <?php echo $_product->getName() ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```